# Function to check GET parameter

Tags: php

I have a function that does a security check on my GET parameter (I'm not the author):

```
function GET($name = NULL, $value = false)
{
    $content = (!empty($_GET[$name]) ? trim($_GET[$name]) : (!empty($value) && !is_array($value) ? trim($value) : false));
    if (is_numeric($content))
        return preg_replace("@([^0-9])@Ui", "", $content);
    else if (is_bool($content))
        return ($content ? true : false);
    else if (is_float($content))
        return preg_replace('@([^0-9\,\.\+\-])@Ui', "", $content);
    else if (is_string($content)) {
        if (filter_var($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            return $content;
        else if (filter_var($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            return $content;
        else if (filter_var($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            return $content;
        else if (filter_var($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT))
            return $content;
        else
            return preg_replace('@([^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\_\*\@\$\!\;\.\?\#\:\=\%\/\ ]+)@Ui', "", $content);
    } else false;
}
```

So whenever I'm fetching GET parameter values I call this function. However, if my GET parameter is a string containing special characters like `åäö` they get replaced. For example, this string `Detta är en annons` will have the following output: `Detta r en annons`.

Since I'm sure it's a string variable it's probably the `filter_var` function that strips my special chars. How should I rewrite the above script to keep my special characters in my string?

**Edit**

Okay, so above script is thrash. I've been looking at alternatives. If my purpose is to insert the GET parameter value into a database, will `filter_input(INPUT_GET,"link",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` be sufficient to clean my variable from any malicious code?

Comment: that function is just plain dumb. you filter based on what you KNOW should be in there. you don't just throw every filter possible at it and see if anything sticks.

Comment: what is the string used for?  this is an awful lot of cleaning.  there may be a much simpler approach here.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using this function. Have a look at [Smart way to protect $_GET vars from malicious injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31502122/53114).

Comment: I'm open for suggestions @MarcB :-) Please have in mind that I'm a novice programmer :-)

Comment: @Gumbo I realize that now. Do you have any alternatives to fetch the GET parameter "safley"?

Comment: @Marcus Safely in what manner?

Comment: @Gumbo Safe from malicious code in the GET parameter

Comment: @Marcus The maleficence depends on how you use the value. And there is no universal function that can protect against the various injection weaknesses as each language and context in which the value is to be put requires its own context-depending handling. Better look at fixing this at the drain and not at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly answering your question, the problem lay in the `preg_replace`.  In the original version, any characters other than the ones explicitly listed are replaced by "", effectively removing them from the input.  For example, "2^8" would become "28", because a `^` is not allowed.

To accept any character other than ["invisible control characters and unused code points"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), replace the `preg_replace` in your function with this:

```
return preg_replace('@(\p{C})@ui', "", $content);
```

[Working implementation](http://3v4l.org/YmDiL).

**Edit**

Responding to the OP edit, `filter_input` is a great way to remove potentially dangerous input and *may* be what you want in your *specific* use case.  However, please understand that there isn't a magic bullet solution.  Have a look at [this related SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

At any rate, what you would typically want to do is check that the user input conforms to your storage requirements (type, length, etc), then use prepared statements to insert it into your database, then use output escaping to prevent XSS attacks.  The pseudo-code goes something like this:

```
$foo = isset($_GET['foo') ?? false;
if (is_string($foo) && 0 < strlen($foo) && strlen($foo) < 255) {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (?)');
    $sth->execute(array($foo));
    echo htmlentities($foo);
} else {
    echo 'Error: foo is not valid';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You did answer the question before the edit so +1 for answering the original question. Could you have a look at the edit aswell? I'll still tick your answer but I'd be happy for a second opinion my alternative approach.